# How you can customize your Company Feed on SharePoint Viva Connections web part?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I am brand new in SharePoint Online in modern version and I'm trying to create nice, good-looking feed from Viva Engage on my SharePoint site. But default web parts suggested by SP don't meet my expectations.

I found something like this on web: [Viva Connections](https://www.habaneroconsulting.com/stories/insights/2021/viva-connections-walkthrough)

Do you know how to achieve such a result? I mean that nice, big pictures at the top, company logo with it's name below and title, author and reactions at the bottom, all with that rounded corners shape of each feed.

If it's something custom - how to achieve it, could you please suggest me some guides/manuals?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the viva connections in your SharePoint tenant for using the Viva connections dashboard and cards.

Check more details about enabling viva connections and configuring dashboard at: [Microsoft Viva Connections (Public preview) is rolling out](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/09/12/microsoft-viva-connections-public-preview-is-rolling-out/)

Before enabling the viva connections, you have to set a SharePoint home site in your SharePoint tenant. Follow:

1. [Set up a home site in SharePoint Online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/03/17/set-up-a-home-site-in-sharepoint-online/)
2. [Set up a SharePoint home site from the SharePoint admin center](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/10/22/set-up-a-sharepoint-home-site-from-the-sharepoint-admin-center/)

Once you have your viva connections dashboard ready, you can add SharePoint default available cards (with rounded corners shape) by editing the dashboard page.

If you need any custom functionality or card, you can develop it using SharePoint framework (SPFx) and Adaptive Card Extensions (ACEs).

Check these Microsoft official documentations:

1. [Overview of the SharePoint Framework (SPFx)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)
2. [Build your first SharePoint Adaptive Card Extension (ACE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/viva/get-started/build-first-sharepoint-adaptive-card-extension)